# mysql выбрать строку, если нету у значения нет дубликата

Tags: mysql

Есть столбец:

```
ID || RATING || NAME
1  || 4      || Дима
2  || 4      || Женя
3  || 5      || Катя
4  || 6      || Дима
5  || 7      || Маша
6  || 5      || Валера
```

Смотрим на столбик RATING: ага, есть две четверки и две пятёрки, значит ОБА значения не берем. Получаем:

```
ID || RATING || NAME
4  || 6      || Дима
5  || 7      || Маша
```

Answer (score 0):

Выбрали не дубликаты в подзапросе, и соединили основную таблицу с ним

```
select
  A.*
from `tbl` A
  JOIN 
  (
   select
     `RATING`,
     count(*) `count`
   from `tbl`
   group by 
     `RATING`
   having `count` = 1
  ) B 
  on A.`RATING` = B.`RATING`
```